# Enable anonymous access in SharePoint 2010 not working, can't access my SharePoint site anonymous

Tags: authentication, anonymous-authentication

I have tried to enable anonymous access in SharePoint 2010 for quite a while now, but it just won't work. I have followed many of the guides out there to enable anonymous access, eg [Enable Anonymous Access in SharePoint 2010.](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010)

When I try to access my SharePoint site anonymously I don't get any login dialog, but I get a **403 FORBIDDEN error.**

I have checked that the "Anonymous Authentication" is enabled in the IIS. I get the same error regardless browser.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Few things that you should see:

- Make sure the default page is checked-in and approved (if its checked-out or pending for approval, it won't be available to anonymous users)
- Make sure all items in Style Library/Site Assets are checked-in and all these libraries have Anonymous Access (sometimes Style Library/Site Assets are not inheriting permissions from Site, so you need to explicitly tell these to inherit or turn on Anonymous Access)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Commented out all the code that has SPContext.Current and then it works. Read this blog post: http://steveclements.net/blog/Gotcha-403-and-401-errors-in-SharePoint-using-Anonymous-access.